# Do you get reputation for self-answered questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation, self-answer

From time to time I ask a question on Stack Overflow. The community is incredibly fast and correct, but sometimes I beat them to it and answer my own question after some research.
Not that it matters a lot, but I used to earn some reputation when answering my own question. This time though, I didn't get any. Is there a limit on answering your question, or has there been a change of policy?

Comment: _I used to earn some reputation when answering my own question_ really? could you provide a link to an example of such answer?

Comment: I am assuming you mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485971/nested-relations-in-drupal

Comment: Yup, that's the one

Comment: You mean you gained 15 rep from having your own answer accepted?

Comment: No no no. I got 2 rep from time to time when answering my own question

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can answer your own question - you will get reputation if it gets upvoted (assuming you did not mark it as Community Wiki).

There is no time limit for getting reputation for upvotes... I am still getting some rep for posts over 3 years old.

Additionally, if *someone else* starts a bounty on one of your questions, they can award their bounty to your self-answer, and it will be considered by the system if the bounty is to be awarded automatically.

You don't gain any reputation from accepting your own answer, and you can't award a bounty that *you* started to your own answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this clarification. I must of gain the reputation in another way I guess :-)

Comment: @Michiel - Answering questions is the best way to gain reputation. 10 points per upvote instead of a single 2 points per accept.

Comment: "`You don't gain reputation from accepting your own answer.`" -- Thank you for confirming. I have searched meta se and so and finally found exactly what I needed. I did't even see this in http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get reputation for accepting your own answers, as @Oded already mentioned, but you will get the reputation from upvotes on your answer which show that people got help from your answer.

If you have faced a problem and couldn't find a solution, and had found a proper solution for it later and want to store it somewhere easy to find, you have something useful that is worth posting a question about. This will save other people the trouble you took, so there is no harm in posting it on the appropriate Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score -10):

Policy apart, you are *supposed* to do the research first and ask later, I guess. That way, you have not only been getting some unfairly gained reps (unfairly because you did what you should have done anyway and because you did it too late for the question and too early for the others to catchup), but ... [let me post this much first -may edit to add more] :) :)

Comment: Some issues are very difficult to find solutions to.  I've run into some very obscure programming problems in the past and asked on SO after many hours of researching.  I didn't stop researching just to wait and see if I had any answers, and yes, sometimes I found the solution on my own.

Comment: Indeed. Sometimes it took me days or weeks to find a decent solution. And when I found it, I want to share it with the community. So I don't see any harm in answering your own questions if you've got the proper solution to it...

Comment: @AndyE'shead: You have obviously missed the smileys at the end: That was not supposed to be some serious solution offered.

Comment: @Michiel: Same as above.

Comment: Yep, saw that, deleted.

Comment: @Kris: I know :-)

Comment: I disagree about "unfairly gained reps" - if the answer is good, it doesn't matter who posted it - even the one asking the question.

Comment: @Kris: no amount of smileys make a post down vote proof :) :) :)

Comment: Answering your own questions is explicitly encouraged. You can even ask a question and answer it yourself if you already know the answer. ([link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking))